# How to get android widget id of a single widget?

Tags: android

With the below code, we get the list of all android widgets we have.

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager    =   AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context,  WidgetProvider.class);
int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
```

But how i can get the id of the widget i just clicked? That means i have 3 or 4 widgets and when i click on one of them, i need to get id of the widget on which i clicked.

How to get it?
I tried below function

```
public static int getWidgetId(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    int appWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
    if (extras != null) {
        appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }
    return appWidgetId;
}
```

But that's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're setting a `setOnClickPendingIntent()` to one of the layout elements in your Widget. Just set the `appWidgetId` as an extra to your `Intent`.
Following the basic idea:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    int appWidgetId;

    // Create an Intent for every Widget by iterating over the appWidgetIds array
    // appWidgetIds array contains all Widgets
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
        // Add the appWidgetId to the Intent
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        // TODO init RemoteViews
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.myView, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

By doing this you can call your function **getWidgetId** in your Activity and should get the corresponding appWidgetId.